# Incorrect order total showing in sales order

Tags: orders, sales, totals

We are using Magento CE 1.7.0.2, Incorrect order total showing in sales order due to price round issue.

```
Subtotal                             $15.98
Shipping & Handling                  $6.95
Discount (10% off any size order)   -$1.60
Tax                                  $1.81
Grand Total                          $23.15
Total Paid                           $0.00
Total Refunded                       $0.00
Total Due                            $23.15
```

As per above totals, if we calculate mathematically, grand total value should be $23.14 but it is showing $23.15, when we print total without using formatPrice() function, it is showing 23.1452.

Can anyone help me to resolve such issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: formatPrice() function rounds to up

Comment: formatPrice() function rounds up, but it returns incorrect result, instead of $23.14 it returns $23.15

Answer (score 0):

I have got this kind of issue with paypal order total . Please see below my solution .
`app/code/core/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation.php` Line 466
change:

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax=false, $round=true)
```

TO

```
public function calcTaxAmount($price, $taxRate, $priceIncludeTax=false, $round=false)
```

Or

You can get  alternate solution for  format price function  .

```
<?php echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency('100.00',true,false); ?>
```

OR

`<?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol(); ?>` and Amount .

Answer (score 0):

If we round the number 23.1452 up to 2 decimals it should be 23.15, try to round in excel (=ROUND(23.1452,2)). 
And be careful with rounding prices and totals while sending them to payment, it better to use standard Magento functionality.

Comment: Ya as per math it is correct rounded value. But if you see in above total, it will calculate 23.14